# Java: Gzip string to output string

Tags: java, http, post, gzip

How do I take a string and use something like [GZIPOutputStream](http://ermalaev.spb.ru/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/zip/GZIPOutputStream.html) to gzip the string and then output the zipped content as a string.

My intention is to transfer the zipped content as a post variable through HTTP.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The steps are actually pretty simple:

- Use the GZIPOutputStream to write it to a ByteArrayOutputStream... close the GZIPOutputStream
- Call ByteArrayOutputStream.toBytes() to get the byte array
- Use a Base64 encoder on the result

The server will perform essentially the reverse of these operations.