# Manual gzip encoding for CamelMessage Response (Content-Length mismatches)

Tags: scala, apache-camel

I am trying to manually gzip a response string being returned via Camel/Jetty. I've modeled my code (below) off what other users have posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2103855/java-gzip-string-to-output-string) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9814164/http-gzip-encoding-of-html), but am still not having any luck. The body being returned in FireBug is garbage (ex. �«æRPP*J...etc.). I've tried tweaking buffer flush modes, base64-ing the ByteArrayBuffer output, and whatever else I can think to throw at it.

One interesting thing I've noticed that could be a clue, is the byte-array size that I print out in my code below (and then use to set the Content-Length header) does not match the Content-Length header showing up in FireBug. For example, data listed as 47 bytes comes out as 62 on the other end, and 153 bytes results in length 176 in FireBug -- The difference in byte-sizes are inconsistent between different sample inputs. Any ideas what Camel/Jetty is doing under the covers that is causing that number to change?

```
val baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
val gzos = new GZIPOutputStream(baos)
gzos.write(response_string.getBytes("UTF-8"))
gzos.flush()
gzos.close()
val bts = baos.toByteArray()
println("SIZE %d".format(bts.size))

client ! CamelMessage(bts,Map(Exchange.CONTENT_TYPE->"text/plain; charset=UTF-8",
                              Exchange.CONTENT_ENCODING->"gzip",
                              Exchange.CONTENT_LENGTH->bts.size))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I broke out WireShark to compare my HTTP responses to other gzip HTTP responses and managed to figure out the problem. For future people trying to do this:

When you specify CONTENT_ENCODING to gzip within the CamelMessage() object, the consumer will automatically compress the response for you somewhere in the post-processing. I don't know if this feature is specific to akka-camel or if its part of jetty. So, in my original code, my output was being compressed, then compressed again by Jetty. This is why my CONTENT_LENGTH values were going up (you can't further compress compressed data, and then it was probably adding another layer of gzip headers).

In short: The compressed data was being recompressed by Jetty, then uncompressed in my browser returning the original compressed data rather than the raw uncompressed string.